# SQL Min Max Values for Two tables and repeating group

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have done some research and I could not find an answer really, I found a little bit that is working well and surprise me a lot because it is so simple but, still not getting result as I have to. So, I have two tables, EMP & DEPT, and I have to answer question "Display the department name along with the lowest and highest salaries in each department".

EMP

---

```
EMPNO   ENAME   JOB          MGR    HIREDATE    SAL     COMM    DEPTNO
7782    CLARK   MANAGER     7839    09/JUN/1981 2450    -       10
7934    MILLER  CLERK       7782    23/JAN/1982 1300    -       10
7788    SCOTT   ANALYST     7566    09/DEC/1982 3000    -       20
7876    ADAMS   CLERK       7788    12/JAN/1983 1100    -       20
7369    SMITH   CLERK       7902    17/DEC/1980 800     -       20
7902    FORD    ANALYST     7566    03/DEC/1981 3000    -       20
7566    JONES   MANAGER     7839    02/APR/1981 2975    -       20
7900    JAMES   CLERK       7698    03/DEC/1981 950     -       30
7499    ALLEN   SALESMAN    7698    20/FEB/1981 1600    300     30
7698    BLAKE   MANAGER     7839    01/MAY/1981 2850    -       30
7654    MARTIN  SALESMAN    7698    28/SEP/1981 1200    1250    30
7844    TURNER  SALESMAN    7698    08/SEP/1981 1500    0       30
7521    WARD    SALESMAN    7698    22/FEB/1981 1250    500     30
7839    KING    PRESIDENT    -      17/NOV/1981 5000    -       -
```

DEPT

---

```
DEPTNO  DNAME       LOC
10      ACCOUNTING  NEW YORK
20      RESEARCH    DALLAS
30      SALES       CHICAGO
40      OPERATIONS  BOSTON
50      PURCHASING  MIAMI
```

Any ideas how to make it working? I have used:

```
SELECT DEPTNO,MIN(SAL) MINI,MAX(SAL) MAXI FROM EMP 
WHERE DEPTNO IS NOT NULL GROUP BY DEPTNO ORDER BY DEPTNO,MINI,MAXI;
```

And I do have a result in what I want but instead of Department Name I do have Department Number. Any tips? How to use `INNER JOIN` on it as when I try it says

> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: Do you want anything shown for Departments 40 and 50? (Showing `null` for mini and maxi?) In most business situations, you do. If so, use an outer join instead of an inner join - that is exactly the difference between the two concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i didn't find any kind of join in your query, so you need to include `join` (i.e. `INNER JOIN` / `LEFT JOIN`)

```
select d.dname, min(e.sal) as MinSal, max(e.sal) as MaxSal
from emp e 
inner join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
group by d.dname;
```

Comment: Thank you, I've just realised I am an idiot, it was so simple and I tried to over complicate it. I have done that exactly now:

`SELECT DNAME,MIN(SAL) MINI,MAX(SAL) MAXI FROM EMP INNER JOIN DEPT ON EMP.DEPTNO = DEPT.DEPTNO GROUP BY DNAME;`

Thank you for help anyway!